# MS Access 2010, how to get the yellow Enable Content bar to show up again?

Tags: vba, ms-access, activex, ms-access-2010

I accidentally closed out the yellow bar that asks to enable Active Content or whatever, and now I can't get it to show up again so I can enable it. Without it, some VBA on the backend doesn't seem to work (it's used in a query) so I need to enable everything etc. How can I get the notification back and enable all VBA/etc?

Comment: Is this happening when you reopen the database or Access?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this in Access 2010. After closing the yellow security warning bar (by clicking the `x` on the right-hand side) simply click the `File` tab on the ribbon bar and then click the big "Enable Content" button:

[image: SecurityTest.png]