# MS Access form doesn't update for a file's copy

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a form in which I have a combo box, this combo box is a `select name from table` from an sql server . Then I have multiple listboxes which query different tables. 
I have an `event after update` for re-querying the data when I choose a value from the combobox. Everything works great.

The problem appears when I make a copy of the .accdb file. I click on the drop down in the combo box to select a name (the list appears) and then nothing happens unless I click on refresh all (If I do it, everything looks great again). Which is strange because I made NO modifications to the copy. Simply copy paste.

What can be the cause of this? It is driving me insane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like security settings.

You have told Access at some point that your original file is safe and that it should enable its (VBA) contents.

In the copy you should see a yellow bar where you can enable the code.

If the yellow bar isn't there, see [MS Access 2010, how to get the yellow Enable Content bar to show up again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280244/ms-access-2010-how-to-get-the-yellow-enable-content-bar-to-show-up-again)

Comment: you were right, just tested it. Many thanks, I tried to write some code to refresh all automatically after the combo box would lose focus and thought of many things except for this.